# ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)") None

Tags: python, linux, odbc, pyodbc

I am trying to use I series driver with pyodbc using unixODBC driver and i am having issues connecting 
Pyodc v- 4.0.31
ibmiacccess 1..1.0.15-1.0

> ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
> None

```
avail = pyodbc.drivers()
print (avail)
drivers = [item for item in pyodbc.drivers()]
driver = drivers[-1]
sys = 'xxxxxxxxx'
uname = 'dbuser'
pas ='xxxxxx'
try:
    connection = pyodbc.connect(
    DRIVER= {driver} ,   
    system= {sys},
    uid= {uname},
    pwd={pas},
    autocommit=True)
    
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    x = cursor.fetchall()
    
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        x = None

finally:
    exit
```

I am able to connect to isql -v

```
#isql -v dbuser
    +---------------------------------------+
    | Connected!                            |
    |                                       |
    | sql-statement                         |
    | help [tablename]                      |
    | quit                                  |
    |                                       |
    +---------------------------------------+
    
    configured odbcinist.ini and odbc.ini follows :
    [ODBC Data Sources]
    dbuser = IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit
    Default = IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit
    
    [dbuser]
    Description             = IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit
    Driver                  = IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit
    System                  = xxxxxxx
    UserID                  = xxxx
    Password                = xxxx
    Naming                  = 0
    DefaultLibraries        = QGPL
    Database                =
    ConnectionType          = 0
    CommitMode              = 2
    ExtendedDynamic         = 1
    DefaultPkgLibrary       = QGPL
    DefaultPackage          = A/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512
    AllowDataCompression    = 1
    MaxFieldLength          = 32
    BlockFetch              = 1
    BlockSizeKB             = 128
    ExtendedColInfo         = 0
    LibraryView             = ENU
    AllowUnsupportedChar    = 0
    ForceTranslation        = 0
    Trace                   = 0
 -----------------------------------   
    
    [IBM i Access ODBC Driver]
    Description=IBM i Access for Linux ODBC Driver
    Driver=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib/libcwbodbc.so
    Setup=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
    Driver64=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
    Setup64=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
    Threading=0
    DontDLClose=1
    UsageCount=1
    
    [IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit]
    Description=IBM i Access for Linux 64-bit ODBC Driver
    Driver=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
    Setup=/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
    Threading=0
    DontDLClose=1
    UsageCount=1
```

also linked
any help is great thank you in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with your setup, but if I get a "File not found" while connecting to the driver, the file not found in question is usually an `.so` file. In the simplest case the driver is just missing and not installed. More obscure cases I encountered were 32Bit / 64Bit mismatch, or a dependency of the driver missing (as in an `.so` file not installed on the system). Using the `ldd` shows you all the dynamic libraries your driver depends on.